# Get None from a Fields data in instead of an empty string

Tags: python, wtforms, flask-wtforms

I have this field in the `WTForms` form

```
name = StringField('Name', validators = [Optional(), Length(max = 100)])
```

When the field is submitted empty then `form.name.data` will, as expected, contain an empty string.

Is there some way to make it return `None` in instead of an empty string? It is just because it is very convenient to deal with `null` in the database like in this `update`:

```
update t
set 
    name = coalesce(%(name)s, name),
    other = coalesce(%(other)s, other)
```

With the above code I don't need to check if the field is empty or not and take actions accordingly be it in the Python code on in the SQL code. The `null` with the `coalesce` solves that easily.

Comment: I'd say it's doubtful, as the _actual_ data received from the browser will really contain an empty string for that field. What's wrong with checking your field values and replacing empty strings with `None` yourself? E.g. `whatever_database.insert_record(form.name.data or None, form.other.data or None)`

Comment: @lanzz _What's wrong with..._ Nothing that wrong. It is just that I think it is cleaner to leave that logic to where (IMO) it belongs; the forms processor

Comment: @lanzz _If WTForms had any facility to automatically rewrite form data..._. Indeed it has. Check my answer.

Comment: As a point of interest, if the form data is coming from a JSON POST (rather than an HTML form submission), then a missing key will result in an empty string from the `StringField`. This is counter-intuitive IMO, since it means there's no way to distinguish between 'user did not enter a value for this field' and 'user submitted an empty string', which might have very different semantics in an application (it does in mine).

Answer (score 28, accepted):

There is the `filters` parameter to the `Field` constructor

```
name = StringField(
    'Name', 
    validators = [Optional(), Length(max = 100)], 
    filters = [lambda x: x or None]
)
```

http://wtforms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/fields.html#the-field-base-class

Answer (score 0):

In my case I added a base class for my forms (all forms are inherited from this class):

```
class BaseFrom(FlaskForm):

    @property
    def fields(self) -> dict:
        """Returns a dict of fields with values, a value='' substitutes with None"""

        def process_item(item):
            if isinstance(item, dict):
                return process_dict(item)
            elif isinstance(item, list):
                return process_list(item)
            elif item == '':
                return None
            return item

        def process_dict(d: dict) -> dict:
            return {k: process_item(v) for k, v in d.items()}

        def process_list(l_: list) -> list:
            return [process_item(v) for v in l_]

        return process_dict({f: value.data for f, value in self._fields.items()})
```

So, when an object is being mapped from form input to dataclass, the mapper uses `fields` property to retrieve data from the form

```
@dataclass
class BaseModel:

    @classmethod
    def from_form(cls, obj: dict):
        self = object.__new__(cls)
        for f in dataclasses.fields(cls):
            setattr(self, f.name, obj.get(f.name))
        return self

d = BaseModel.from_form(form_instance.fields)
```

where `form_instance` is an instance of a class inherited from 'BaseForm'

I have nested forms, so this method will convert all empty inputs to None recursively