# Flask - WTForm - Get Form Data as NoneType as opposed to String

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, wtforms, flask-wtforms

I have been searching the internet for a while now in order to solve this issue.

I am working on a proof of concept, a simple input output data entry application.

However, the Form I am using, won't output my NoneType values as I am trying to use `filters` in order to do so, as illustrated in this stackoverflow thread : [Get None from a Fields data in instead of an empty string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21831216/get-none-from-a-fields-data-in-instead-of-an-empty-string)

However the results are not as expected, as I still only receive Strings.

### My Form

```
class MyForm(Form):
    event_date = DateField('Event Date:', format='%Y-%m-%d', validators=[DataRequired()], filters=[lambda x: x or None])
    person = StringField('Person', filters=[lambda x: x or None])
    office = QuerySelectField(query_factory=get_all_offices, allow_blank=True,
                              filters=[lambda x: x or None])
    event_type = QuerySelectField(query_factory=get_all_event_types, allow_blank=True, filters=[lambda x: x or None])
    submit = SubmitField('Search')
```

### Render

```
@app.route('/myform', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def myform():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = MyForm()
        return render_template('my_form.html', form=form)
    else:
        print(request.form)
        context = {}
        event_date = request.form['event_date']
        office = request.form['office']
        person = request.form['person']
        event_type = request.form['event_type']
        print(person)
        print(event_date)
        print(type(office))
        print(event_type)
```

### The Input

[image]

### The Output

[image]

As you can see, office, and event type are coming through as a String Object, with a value of "__None".

Any ideas if it is possible to have the form handle the translation of `''` or `'__None'` to the builtin `NoneType` ?

Edit: Schema for person / office

---

```
class Person(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'people'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    name = Column(String(64), nullable=False)
    political_party = Column(String(64), nullable=False)
    ap_candidate_id = Column(String(64), nullable=False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.name


class Office(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'offices'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    desc = Column(String(64), nullable=False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.desc


class Event(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'events'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    event_date = Column(DateTime, nullable=False)
    office_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(Office.id))
    office = relationship('Office', backref='events')
    winner_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(Person.id))
    winner = relationship('Person', foreign_keys=winner_id, backref='events_won')
    loser_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(Person.id))
    loser = relationship('Person', foreign_keys=loser_id, backref='events_lost')
    event_type_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(EventType.id))
    event_type = relationship('EventType', backref='events')
    state_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(State.id))
    state = relationship('State', backref='state_events')

    def __repr__(self):
        return '{0} - {1}'.format(self.office, self.event_date)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing

```
print request.form['event_date']
```

so basically you are just printing data posted by the browser. You are not even using the `MyForm` class you created. You need to pass your `request.form` data to your `MyForm` class so that it may parse it. And later use your MyForm class instance.

You need to do something like

```
def myform():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = MyForm()
        return render_template('my_form.html', form=form)
    else:
        form = MyForm(request.form)
        if form.validate():
            print form.event_date.data
            print form.office.data
            print form.person.data
            print form.event_type.data
```

For more details, please go through [docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/patterns/wtforms/#in-the-view) about how to handle forms in views.

Comment: This is what I was missing, but a quick question, for me I Had to remove `if form.validate()` in order for hte printing to hit... not sure why

Comment: You can always print form's errors dict `form.errors` to see why form failed validation.

Answer (score 0):

Your filters need to take into account that the value could be the string value `"__None"`, currently your filters are just checking whether the value is absent or not. Something like the following should work (untested).

```
 person = StringField('Person', filters=[lambda x: x or None, lambda x: None if x == '__NONE' else x])
```